# Reading local security policy

Tags: c#, security, gpo

I am trying to read a value from the Local security policies using C#. The value I am trying to read is the Debug Programs under the User Rights Assignment folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, these settings don't get stored in registry. You might have some success using the secedit command line tool. `cmd /c secedit /export /cfg myfile.inf /areas USER_RIGHTS` will generate the inf file which you can then parse to fish out the information you need. Not a very elegant solution, unfortunately, perhaps someone else can offer a better one.