# Get System minimum password length and complexity

Tags: delphi

In local security policy (PC-Control panel-Administration-local security policy) there is a parameter "Minimum length of the password" and a parameter "Password must meet complexity requirements" (true/false). How can I read them in Delphi (for WinXpSp3-Win2003-Vista-Win7-Win2008(+r2))?

[image]

I'm looking for something like:

```
Function DetectSystemMinPassLength:integer;
begin
//?
end;

Function DetectSystemPassComplexity:boolean;
begin
//?
end;
```

Additional question:
Does there exist in Delphi (or WinApi) function which can check if a given password conforms to system policies (or set)?

For example:

```
Function MyCheckPassComplexity (Password:string):boolean;
begin
// ???
end;
```

use

```
MyCheckPassComplexity (' 12345 '); //result False

MyCheckPassComplexity (' MyCoolPassword9999 '); //result True
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API to do these things (which is a shame). See this question for a command line solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850837/reading-local-security-policy There are solutions for Active Directory though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313859/reading-the-local-password-policy-programmatically

Comment: delphi need, not c# & vb

Comment: The first link I posted contains the information you need to read the settings from a file, see RRUZs answer.

Comment: The second link contains a small VBScript example on how to use ADSI, there are ADSI wrappers for Delphi you basically have to query the domain for the information you're looking for.

Comment: ok, how get password complexity with vbscript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually to read a local or group policy setting you must use the [`Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250) which basically is a set of excel files which contains the windows registry keys where is stored such info. unfortunately in this case if you check such reference for these Account policies (Enforce password history,
Maximum password age, Minimum password age, Minimum password length) you will find this message:

```
Password Policy security settings are not registry keys.
```

Exist a set of WMI classes in the `root\RSOP\Computer` namespace like [RSOP_SecuritySettingBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375062.aspx), [RSOP_SecuritySettingNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375064%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ,  [RSOP_SecuritySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375066%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to access the an account policy but these classes only works (I mean retrieve information) on systems which is are in a domain, but it does not work in a workgroup.

For the moment I think which you best option is export the local policies to a ini file using this command (and then parse the result using a TIniFile class)

```
secedit.exe /export /cfg C:\Output\Policy.Ini
```

This command will create a file like this

```
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[System Access]
MinimumPasswordAge = 0
MaximumPasswordAge = 42
MinimumPasswordLength = 0
PasswordComplexity = 0
PasswordHistorySize = 0
```

About your second question to validate a password you can use the [`NetValidatePasswordPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function.

Comment: Well this make me sense because you are accesing a restricted resource of the system.

Comment: It looks like you can query this using Windows API, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31005363/255257).

Comment: @RRUZ, sos un grande, un saludo desde el norte!

Comment: Hola amigo @jachguate, mira donde te vengo a encontrar ;)